# Goto line or restart script

Tags: ruby

I'm coding a calculator. Once a user is done, I want the user to chose to exit or enter another sum. How would I make it ask and accept what they want to do, and exit or restart depending on the result? Here is my [current script](http://gyazo.com/a592baf6f43c065d5112d11f85da10ff).

Comment: Post code, not *screenshots of code*.

Comment: As for the question: the sooner you drop this BASIC way of thinking ("go to line"), the better. Here a loop and a couple of methods would do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to wrap your procedure in a function. You can then do recursion.

Ruby 'like' Psuedo code:

```
 def calculator:
       // your calculator procedure 
  end

  def recur:
        calculator()
        recur() 
  end 

   recur()
```

Most modern languages do not have a `goto` directive. So instead of a `goto` you need to design the flow using functions.

In a language like classic `BASIC` you could have something like:

```
calculator_label:
    // your procedure here
    goto calculator_label
```

In Ruby and a lot of other languages this is not available. So what you do is wrap your code in a function, then at the end of the function you call the function again. This is called "tail recursion". Just like with `goto` you can end up in an infinite loop. Or worse, languages like JavaScript will not properly garbage collect with tail recursion so memory is not freed as it would be expected. This is called a memory leak.

So the goto example above becomes:

```
def calculator:
   // your procedural code here
   calculator()
end

calculator()
```